# Why does the content disappear after adding a border to the DataGrid (WPF C#)

Tags: c#, wpf

I added round corner border to DataGrid:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Border Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource HiGrayBrush}" BorderThickness="1,2,1,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

After border added, the content disappers

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
        <Canvas Height="900" Width="1000">
            <DataGrid x:Name="mDataGrid" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="34" Height="530" Width="510"
                      LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow">
                <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"                    
                               Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow},Path=Header}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            </DataGrid>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="CellTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource HiBlackBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="DataGridHeadStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,0,1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource HiGrayBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,0,-1"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="DataGridRowHeadStyle" TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource HiGrayBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource HiBlackBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,0,0,0"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,0,1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource HiGrayBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource HiBlackBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,0,0"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="FirstDataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource HiGrayBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource HiBlackBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,0,0,0"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="{DynamicResource HiGrayBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="{DynamicResource HiGrayBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Border Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource HiGrayBrush}" BorderThickness="1,2,1,2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

C#:

```
private void initDataGrid()
{
    mDataGrid.SetValue(DataGrid.StyleProperty, Application.Current.FindResource("DataGridStyle"));
    mDataGridList = new List<RegisterValue>();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        mDataGridList.Add(new RegisterValue()
        {
            mId = i.ToString("X01"),
            Data0 = i.ToString("X02"),
            Data1 = (i + 1).ToString("X02"),
            Data2 = (i + 2).ToString("X02"),
            Data3 = (i + 3).ToString("X02"),
            Data4 = (i + 4).ToString("X02"),
            Data5 = (i + 5).ToString("X02"),
            Data6 = (i + 6).ToString("X02"),
            Data7 = (i + 7).ToString("X02"),
            Data8 = (i + 8).ToString("X02"),
            Data9 = (i + 9).ToString("X02"),
            Data10 = (i + 10).ToString("X02"),
            Data11 = (i + 11).ToString("X02"),
            Data12 = (i + 12).ToString("X02"),
            Data13 = (i + 13).ToString("X02"),
            Data14 = (i + 14).ToString("X02"),
            Data15 = (i + 15).ToString("X02"),
        });

        DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        column.Header = Convert.ToUInt32(i).ToString("X01");
        FrameworkElementFactory tempTextBox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
        tempTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("Data" + i));
        tempTextBox.SetValue(TextBox.StyleProperty, Application.Current.FindResource("CellTextBoxStyle"));
        DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        dataTemplate.VisualTree = tempTextBox;
        column.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
        column.SetValue(DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyleProperty, Application.Current.FindResource("DataGridHeadStyle"));
        column.SetValue(DataGridTemplateColumn.WidthProperty, new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star));
        if (i > 0)
        {
            column.SetValue(DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyleProperty, Application.Current.FindResource("DataGridCellStyle"));
        }
        else
        {
            column.SetValue(DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyleProperty, Application.Current.FindResource("FirstDataGridCellStyle"));
        }
        mDataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
    }
    mDataGrid.SetValue(DataGrid.RowHeaderStyleProperty, Application.Current.FindResource("DataGridRowHeadStyle"));
    mDataGrid.ItemsSource = mDataGridList;
}
```

How can I add the border properly?

Comment: The template conttains more than just a border. You must also specify where and how the items are displayed. See [DataGrid ControlTemplate Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#datagrid-controltemplate-example). Every  ItemsControl at least needs an ItemsPresenter in its template.

Comment: you overriding the `Template`. so basically the `DataGrid` docent know to populate the data. just wrap the data grid with `<Border>` and put your properties their

Comment: You replaced all the UI that makes a datagrid visually a datagrid with a border rather than adding that border. You'd need a margin on the border to allow for the rounded corners as well. But I think it's going to look a bit weird. You have a rectangular thing but you seem to want to make it rounded. That is always a bit of a complication.